# Can we use HTML code in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some attractive graph which is made in HTML and javascript.

So my questions are:

1. Can I use this work in my swift app,
2. Can we use javascript and html code to make graph in app?using webview
3. Can we pass values from swift/objective c code to javascript/html code and vice-versa?

If yes , How can we pass variable value to html/javascript and how to to accept this value in HTML

Comment: you should parse the code..http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Answer (score 2):

- html text can be embedded into labels as `NSAttributedString` instances
- HTML content that has scripts and stuff can be put into a web view container: `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`

Answer (score 0):

1. **YES.** Create a webview then load this html page.
2. **YES.**  (same as answer 1)
3. **YES** .

   - To send to html page: call `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];`
   - To send to swift/objective-c : handle `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` of your UIwebview.

   -(BOOL) webView : (UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request navigationType : (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType  {

   ```
   if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"yourPrefixe:"]) {
       //do your works
       //then cancel current request
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks for nice answer..can you give an example where we can send value in variable to html/javascript